# why PyTesseract detect 8 as 3 .?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I wrote a simple function in my app, which converts certain very simple images containing numbers into numbers . thats it ! . but if image has 8  its show's 3 . any help ? this is image example
[image: image example]

also i tried convert my image also to sharpness . its not work perfectly for other numbers . how i can fix it ?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
from pyasn1.type.univ import Null
import requests
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

path_to_tesseract =resource_path(r"Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe")


Startbalance_window = Tk()
        #Setting title of screen
Startbalance_window.title("SS")
        #setting height and width of screen
Startbalance_window.geometry("500x180")
Startbalance_window.configure(background=("#091c2d")) 




path_to_tesseract =resource_path(r"Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe")



pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract



def get_wallet():
    urlentryGP_text = urlentry_GP.get()

    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
    imgURL_GP= Image.open(requests.get(urlentryGP_text, stream=True).raw)
    response = requests.get(urlentryGP_text) 


    width, height = imgURL_GP.size # get image size 
    imgURL_GP = imgURL_GP.resize((800, int(800/(width/height))), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    im_s_1 = imgURL_GP.convert("L") #black&white

    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 outputbase digits'
    query = pytesseract.image_to_string(im_s_1, lang='eng+fra',nice=1,config=custom_config) # getting all text in the image

    image_list2 = query.split()
    OSBALANCE_image21 = image_list2[-1].replace(',',"") #getting last value and remove comma from it
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace('@',"0")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace(';',"")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace(':',"")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace('/',"")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace('L',"")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace('J',"")
    OSBALANCE_image21 = OSBALANCE_image21.replace('I',"")
    print(OSBALANCE_image21)

    sum_balance_text.set(f" Your Balance is: {OSBALANCE_image21} ")
    sum_balance.place(x=265,y=120) 



global urlentry_GP
urlentry_GP = StringVar()
URL_Entry_GP = Entry(Startbalance_window, textvariable=urlentry_GP).place(x=300,y=50)

submit_imagebutton= Button(Startbalance_window, text="Extract Balance", width=10, height=1, bg="orange",command=get_wallet,font='lato 8 bold',cursor="hand2")
submit_imagebutton.place(x=290,y=80, width=148,height=20)
global sum_balance_text
sum_balance_text = StringVar()
sum_balance=Label(Startbalance_window,textvariable=sum_balance_text,bg="#091c2d",fg="white",font=("default",9,"bold"))




Startbalance_window.resizable(0,0)
Startbalance_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can try to process your image with a library like open cv and adjust the background/numbers -- not guaranteed to make a difference but tesseract is an ocr so it wont always be exact

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'bin/tesseract.exe'
tessdata = 'tessdata'

filename = 'WENWg.png'
im = Image.open(filename)
width, height = im.size
scale_factor = 3
im_scaled = im.resize((width*scale_factor, height*scale_factor))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im_scaled, config=f'--psm 6 --tessdata-dir "{tessdata}"').replace('\n\f', ''))
```

Output:

```
Total quide price:
123,802,858
```